# How to merge the hash this way

Tags: ruby, hash

I have written a huge code something like below

```
 headers, *data_rows = @testCaseSheet
    local = headers.zip(*data_rows)
    local = local[1..-1].map {|dataRow| local[0].zip(dataRow).to_h}
    testCaseHash = {}
    local.each do |value|
      testCaseHash[value["Locator"]] = value.tap {|hs| hs.delete("Locator")}
    end
    @testCaseSheet = []
    p testCaseHash
    [h["Test Name"], testCaseHash],
```

which output me this as below, now I need to merge this action with each test, I don't know how to do this.

```
hash= {"Action"=>{"css=#entityType"=>"Type", "id=idNumber"=>"TypeAndWait", "id=shortName"=>"TypeAndTab", "id=FirstName"=>"TypeTabAndWait", nil=>nil}, 

"Test1"=>{"css=#entityType"=>"Individual", "id=idNumber"=>"2323", "id=shortName"=>"M", "id=FirstName"=>"Abc", "id=lastName"=>"Gg"}, 

"Test2"=>{"css=#entityType"=>"Legal", "id=idNumber"=>"2323", "id=shortName"=>"Z", "id=FirstName"=>"Xyz", "id=lastName"=>"Gg"}}
```

Now I want to merge this action with the followings tests for an example,

```
hash= { "Test1"=>{"css=#entityType"=>["Individual","Type"], "id=idNumber"=>["2323","TypeAndWait"], "id=shortName"=>["M","TypeAndTab"], "id=FirstName"=>["Abc","TypeTabAndWait"]}, 

"Test2"=>{"css=#entityType"=>["Legal""Type"], "id=idNumber"=>["2323","TypeAndWait"], "id=shortName"=>["Z","TypeAndTab"], "id=FirstName"=>["Xyz","TypeTabAndWait"]}}
```

I don't know how to merge this way, Can anyone help me?

Comment: You want to manipulate the first hash to get the second? I guess you need to escape the commas: `"id=\"lastName"=>"Gg"` or use `'`

Comment: Yes I need to combine the values for the same key as i have shown.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure if this is your intention, but the name usage suggest a flaw in your code. If you *zip* `headers` with `*data_rows` the output will be columns. This means the variable name in *map* should not be `data_row`, but `column` instead. This column has the header as first element. By doing `local[1..-1].map` you will loop over all columns except the first one.

Comment: Hi that's the part of the code , since that's not necessary here , i have added a part . If you want to see the whole code i will add it tomorrow.

Comment: @Rajagopalan There is no need to add the whole code (it clutters the question), I just wanted to make sure that your approach was intentional.

Comment: @Johan Wentholt okay, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you want something like this

```
hash_1 = {a: "a1", b: "b1", c: "c1"}
hash_2 = {a: "a2", b: "b2", d: "d1"}

p hash_1.merge(hash_2) { |k, v1, v2| v1 = [v1, v2] }
# => {:a=>["a1", "a2"], :b=>["b1", "b2"], :c=>"c1", :d=>"d1"}
```

Which in your case can be:

```
test_1_value = my_hash['Test1'].merge(my_hash['Action']) { |k, v1, v2| v1 = [v1, v2] }

# => {"css=#entityType"=>["Individual", "Type"], "id=idNumber"=>["2323", "TypeAndWait"], "id=shortName"=>["M", "TypeAndTab"], "id=FirstName"=>["Abc", "TypeTabAndWait"], "id=\"lastName"=>"Gg", nil=>nil}
```

This is a general solution, you can manipulate furthermore removing the unwanted keys ad apply to fit your needs.

#### Edit - picking up comments

Remove unwanted keys and simplified merge block:

```
keys_to_remove = ["id=lastName", "whatever", nil]
test_1_value = my_hash['Test1'].merge(my_hash['Action']) { |k, *vs| vs }.delete_if{ |k, _| keys_to_remove.include? k }
# => {"css=#entityType"=>["Individual", "Type"], "id=idNumber"=>["2323", "TypeAndWait"], "id=shortName"=>["M", "TypeAndTab"], "id=FirstName"=>["Abc", "TypeTabAndWait"]}
```

Comment: Hi, thats perfect , I wrongly given the "id="last name" instead of "id=last name" as key and this key is not in action so this should not come in result .

Comment: This can be further simplified to a merge block of: `{ |k, *vs| vs }`.

Comment: @JohanWentholt, thanks did't know this, added to my knowledge.

Comment: @iGian I [expanded a bit on your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52044462/3982562), hope you don't mind. You're free to include my expansion into your answer if you want. If you do, notify my by leaving a comment under my answer so I can remove it.

Comment: @Johan Wentholt please don't remove it, I want your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, it might be a good idea to build up the desired data structure while dealing with the underlaying data objects. However, if you need to transform you hash afterwards, here is one way to do that:

```
hash = {
    "Action"=>{"css=#entityType"=>"Type", "id=idNumber"=>"TypeAndWait", "id=shortName"=>"TypeAndTab", "id=FirstName"=>"TypeTabAndWait", nil=>nil}, 
    "Test1"=>{"css=#entityType"=>"Individual", "id=idNumber"=>"2323", "id=shortName"=>"M", "id=FirstName"=>"Abc", "id=lastName"=>"Gg"}, 
    "Test2"=>{"css=#entityType"=>"Legal", "id=idNumber"=>"2323", "id=shortName"=>"Z", "id=FirstName"=>"Xyz", "id=lastName"=>"Gg"}
  }

action = hash['Action']
tests = hash.reject { |k, v| k == 'Action' }


mapping = tests.map do |name, test|
  groups = (action.to_a + test.to_a).group_by(&:first)
  no_keys = groups.map { |k, v| [k, v.each(&:shift).flatten] }
  no_keys.reject! { |k, v| v.length == 1 }
  [name, Hash[no_keys]]
end

Hash[mapping]
#  => {"Test1"=>{"css=#entityType"=>["Type", "Individual"], "id=idNumber"=>["TypeAndWait", "2323"], "id=shortName"=>["TypeAndTab", "M"], "id=FirstName"=>["TypeTabAndWait", "Abc"]},
#      "Test2"=>{"css=#entityType"=>["Type", "Legal"], "id=idNumber"=>["TypeAndWait", "2323"], "id=shortName"=>["TypeAndTab", "Z"], "id=FirstName"=>["TypeTabAndWait", "Xyz"]}}
```

I hope you find that useful.

Comment: Hi, thank you , this is nearly perfect and that's what I want but in a my given output, If action is nil then that should be in output and also if key which is not available in the action is available in the test, that should not be included in the resultant set but your output is including that as well.

Comment: Also `action = hash['Action'].compact`

Comment: @Rajagopalan addressed comment, I updated my answer to reject all values containing only one element.

Answer (score 2):

I want to expand on [iGians answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52043314/3982562). Although the answer describes how the issue should be solved, it didn't use any iteration. You can iterate over the tests in the following way:

```
hash = {
  "Action"=>{"css=#entityType"=>"Type", "id=idNumber"=>"TypeAndWait", "id=shortName"=>"TypeAndTab", "id=FirstName"=>"TypeTabAndWait", nil=>nil}, 
  "Test1"=>{"css=#entityType"=>"Individual", "id=idNumber"=>"2323", "id=shortName"=>"M", "id=FirstName"=>"Abc", "id=lastName"=>"Gg"}, 
  "Test2"=>{"css=#entityType"=>"Legal", "id=idNumber"=>"2323", "id=shortName"=>"Z", "id=FirstName"=>"Xyz", "id=lastName"=>"Gg"},
}

action = hash.delete 'Action'
tests = hash

tests.each_value do |test|
  action_with_test_keys = action.select { |key, _value| test.key? key }
  test.merge!(action_with_test_keys) { |_key, *values| values } # values = [old, new]
end
```

This assumes that `'Action'` is the only non-test key in the hash and all other values should be merged with the `'Action'` value. **Keep in mind that this approach mutates the `hash` variable. If you don't want this you should simply [`#dup`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Object.html#method-i-dup) the hash beforehand or look for a non-mutating approach.**

**Optimizations**:

If you use Ruby 2.5.0 or higher you can use [`#slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-slice) instead of [`#select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-select).

```
action.select { |key, _value| test.key? key }
# is replaced with
action.slice(*test.keys)
```

If you are 100% sure that each `test` in `tests` contains the same keys and there is always at least one test present, you could move the `action_with_test_keys` assignment out of the `#each_value` block to save resources.

```
tests = hash # anchor point in the above solution
action_with_test_keys = action.slice(*tests.values.first.keys) # added
```

**References**:

- [`Hash#delete`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-delete) to remove the `'Action'` key from the `hash` variable.
- [`Hash#each_value`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-each_value) to iterate over each value of `tests`.
- [`Hash#select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-select) to select only the `action` keys that are present on `test`.
- [`Hash#key?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-key-3F) to check if the given key is present.
- [`Hash#merge!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-merge-21) to merge `action_with_test_keys` and update the `test` variable.
- [`Hash#slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-slice) replacement for `Hash#select` if you use Ruby 2.5.0 or higher.

Comment: That's much better but Unwanted values can't known like you have done! If action doesn't have the key and that key exists in the test hash then it's unwanted key.

Comment: @Rajagopalan Ah, that clears things up. I'll add it in.

Comment: Oh, I might have interpreted it wrong. I [currently](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/52044462/3) merge only the action keys that are in the test. I guess this should be the other way around.

Comment: Amazing, actually yours is more perfect, I have invited your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @JohanWentholt Excellent! There is always room for improvement and learning. Also, there is not scarcity of upvotes, so..